# Cost of adding an index when another already exists in the same order

Tags: sql, indexing, db2

Working with DB2 10 on z/os. My question is if adding an index on a column would have the normal cost of adding an index if there is already another index (non-clustered) on a col concatenation of my column and other column(s), e.g. want to add an index to col1 when an index exists on col4, which is a concatenation of col1 and col2.

In case your curious about the situation. We created some tables when converting from another database, and the keys were on combined fields. To mimic the old keys (and so not rewrite our whole system), but have these fields split out so they are useful, we have tables with all the old individual columns and some new columns for the keys which are created by triggers (on insert) by concatenating some columns, n.b. when they are not equal to spaces, and these new columns are indexed.

So, for example a table has col1 (char), col2 (char), and col3 and creates indexed col4 as a concatenation of col1 and col2 on insert.

This was done so col4 would match our old database, e.g. doesn't exist if col1 or col2 are blank.

Well, the downside was that this was done as a blanket rule and on some tables col1 and col2 are never blank. So an index on col1, col2 would be the same...and is actually preferred because sometimes we only want to search by col1 (not w/ col2)...and especially use it in joins to other tables.

So...in that case, does db2 gain any advantage from the non-clustered index that is pretty much the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as DB2 is concerned, they're complete separate columns (which they are), and the costs of adding an index (updating the index for `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, and `DELETE`s) cannot be "short-circuited" just because you have an index on another column that just happens to be the result of a concatenation of two other columns.

If you still query on `col4`, I would leave an index on that. I would then add a new index on `(col1, col2)`.